# How to pass properties, using next JS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need to pass a property when I invoke a component, but it's not working. 
I'm starting with next JS and this is confusing to me.

```
//Component

const Container: React.FC = (props) => (
  <section className="container-red">
    <h1>{props.title}</h1>
  </section>
);

export default Container;



//----------------------

import Container from "../../components/Container";

const FaqCustomer: React.FC = () => (
  <div>
    <Container title="Title Page" />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: What error are you facing?? Are you using typescript??

Comment: Yes. Property 'title' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'

Comment: You need to declare ```title``` in container component as a react property.. Please look at the answer below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the props and its type in `Container` component.

Make an interface and assign the `title` and its type like,

```
interface IContainerProps {
   title: string;
}
```

Then use the interface like,

```
React.FC<IContainerProps> = props => ( ... )
```

And the code in container looks like,

**components/container.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";

interface IContainerProps {
  title: string;
}

const Container: React.FC<IContainerProps> = props => (
  <section className="container-red">
    <h1>{props.title}</h1>
  </section>
);

export default Container;
```

> [**Working Sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fc-hooks-9j4w3)